# Restricting a user to save more than 10 documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am not sure what would be the best way to handle this. I want to restrict user to save more than 10 documents. I have collection like

```
DataCollection > {item-documents}
```

structure of item-document

```
{
    id: auto-generated
    uid: user-uid
    .... // other data
}
```

Option 1:
Before saving a document, I can get the count of total items saved by this user and can restrict. But I think it can be cheated by mocking API response

Option 2:
Is there any way to restrict a write operation in Rules?

Answer (score 2):

**NEW ANSWER following below comment from @FrankvanPuffelen:**

You can maintain one counter document per user. More precisely, in a specific collection (e.g. `userDocumentCounters`), you create one document per user that you update each time a **main** document is created by a user. For that you can use a [Batched Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) together with the [`increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value) method.

In order to avoid the user to cheat, you assign these `create` and `update` security rules to the `userDocumentCounters` collection (the field containing the counter value is named `count` in this example):

```
match /userDocumentCounters/{docId} {
  // Applies to writes to nonexistent documents
  allow create: request.resource.data.count == 1;

  // Applies to writes to existing documents
  allow update: if request.resource.data.count < 11 && request.resource.data.count > resource.data.count;

  // Applies to delete operations
  allow delete: if <condition>;
}
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

One possibility would be to have a Cloud Function that updates a counter by user each time a document is created (and deleted?).

This counter is saved in one document by user that you can read in the security rules with the [`get()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

The advantage of using a Cloud Function is that you can deny any access to the collection containing the counter docs since the Cloud Function uses the Admin SDK which bypasses the security rules.

An important(?) drawback is the fact that the counter update will not be instantaneous, even if you configure the Cloud Function to have one or more instances always available.

Comment: Why not have the client-side code write the counter, enforce that it does this with security rules, and then enforce the maximum document count in security rules too?

Comment: You are right @FrankvanPuffelen :-) ! I was too fast and didn't envision how to do that with security rules   `allow update: if request.resource.data.count < 11 && request.resource.data.count > resource.data.count;` would do the trick. I'll delete my answer and let you answer.

Comment: After two days I undeleted and updated my initial answer :-)

Comment: Nice! Thanks Renaud! --- I'm actually considering writing. security rules for this use-case (including the increment/decrement) once and for all, but will post a new question if I do.